how to make request to Shopify Admin API in graphql with java generated classes
I need help to understand how to make request to Shopify Admin API in graphql with java generated classes. I used this tool : https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen to generate the classes but I don't understand how to use them. I want to retrieve an order from a payment_id.
I tried to follow the example in the README but I didn't succeed to reproduce the query() function call and I didn't find any other resources or documentation to help me...
